# RequireJS: CDN fallback not working with Kendo

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, requirejs, cdn, fallback

Struggling to set up RequireJS with KendoUI over CDN and can't get fallback to work.

... from amazing burkeholland [A Kendo UI ASP.NET MVC SPA Template](http://a.shinynew.me/post/78038782111/a-kendo-ui-asp-net-mvc-spa-template)

This what I begin with :

```
define([
    '../Scripts/kendo/2014.1.416/kendo.router.min',
    '../Scripts/kendo/2014.1.416/kendo.view.min',
    '../Scripts/kendo/2014.1.416/kendo.fx.min'
], function () {
    return kendo;
})
```

and it works fine. 
If kendo.core.min is not defined, first statement in kendo.router says `define(["./kendo.core.min"]` and it is loaded from proper location.

However, when I try to use CDN with fallback location like this :

```
requirejs.config({
    paths: {       
        'router': ['//cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.1.416/js/kendo.router.min', '../Scripts/kendo/2014.1.416/kendo.router.min'],
        'view': ['//cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.1.416/js/kendo.view.min', '../Scripts/kendo/2014.1.416/kendo.view.min'],
        'fx': ['//cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.1.416/js/kendo.fx.min', '../Scripts/kendo/2014.1.416/kendo.fx.min']
    }
});
define([
   'router',
   'view',
   'fx'
], function () {
    return kendo;
});
```

requireJS tries to load kendo.core.min from baseUrl location, not fallback location.

Am I missing something?

However, if I try something like this :

```
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        k: ['//cdn.kendostatic.com/2014.1.416/js', '../Scripts/kendo/2014.1.416']
    }
});
define([
   'k/kendo.router.min',
   'k/kendo.view.min',
   'k/kendo.fx.min'
], function () {
    return kendo;
})
```

Fallback doesn't work at all... what am I missing?